# Halogen vs H-Bond Donor/Acceptor: How do they differ?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-design

I know that in rational design sometimes the researcher might use Cl or F instead of  a H-Bond donor/acceptor. **What kind of interaction does a halogen provide compared to the H-bond donor/acceptor? When might it be better to use one compared to another for best binding affinity?**

Below is a picture of a small molecule in an active site. I am considering if should use a H-bond donor or a Halogen to complement the carboxylic acid (skinny line structure with red oxygen in upper left). I want the most attraction to occur between the small molecule and the active site.

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halogen_bond